# Python двумерные массивы

Tags: python, массивы

Начинаю изучать Python, вот вопрос:
Создаю массив и присваиваю элементу значение -

```py
x=[[0]*3]*5
print(x)

x[0][0]=1
print(x)
```

---

[[0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0]]

[[1, 0, 0], [1, 0, 0], [1, 0, 0], [1, 0, 0], [1, 0, 0]]

Почему он присваивает целой строке значение?

Answer (score 2):

Пусть нам нужно создать двумерный список из 3 строк и 4 столбцов, заполненный нулями. Кажется, что такой двумерный список можно создать следующим образом: `a = [[0] * 4] * 3`. Но тут возникает проблема. При таком способе `a[0]`, `a[1]` и `a[2]` являются ссылками на один и тот же список `[0] * 4`. Поэтому после операции `a[0][0] = 1`, окажется, что элементы `a[1][0]` и `a[2][0]` тоже стали равны числу 1.

Чтобы правильно создать двумерный список, заполненный нулями и состоящий из n строк и m столбцов, необходимо, чтобы каждая строка списка создавалась заново. Есть несколько способов сделать это.

Например, можно создать список из n нулей, а затем каждый элемент этого списка заменить на список из m нулей. Во время замены список из m нулей будет создаваться заново, поэтому каждая из n строк окажется ссылкой на свой независимый список из m нулей:

```
a = [0] * n
for i in range(n):
    a[i] = [0] * m
```

Можно создать изначально пустой список, а потом n раз добавить в конец этого списка новый элемент, который является списком из m нулей:

```
a = []
for i in range(n):
    a.append([0] * m)
```

Также для создания двумерного списка можно использовать генератор, который создает список из n элементов, каждый из которых будет списком, состоящим из m нулей (подробнее о генераторах списков будет рассказано в следующем модуле):

```
a = [[0] * m for i in range(n)]
```

В каждом из этих трёх способов очередная строка создается независимо от остальных: заново конструируется список `[0] * m`, а не копируются ссылки на один и тот же список.

***Взято с платформы Сириус.Курсы***